# wkhtmltopdf is addind 'http://' before file path

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf on my website, but when I generate a pdf from an html source, the command executed is somethink like:

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality --orientation 'portrait' --encoding 'utf-8' --javascript-delay '5000' --footer-right ' 07/15/2021 1638036' '/tmp/knp_snappy60f059079d55d8.51993277.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy60f059079d5ef5.15668691.pdf'
```

And i got the error:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks                  ] 5%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
Error: Failed loading page http:///tmp/knp_snappy60f059079d55d8.51993277.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error wi
th --load-error-handling ignore)
Warning: Failed loading page http:///tmp/knp_snappy60f059079d5ef5.15668691.pdf (ignored)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
```

As we can see on lines:

```
Error: Failed loading page http:///tmp/knp_snappy60f059079d55d8.51993277.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error wi
th --load-error-handling ignore)
Warning: Failed loading page http:///tmp/knp_snappy60f059079d5ef5.15668691.pdf (ignored)
```

wkhtmltopdf  is adding '**http://**' before the absolute path. I think the problem is there...

How can we disabled this behaviour ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
file:///tmp/knp_snappy60f059079d55d8.51993277.html
```

need add `file:///` schema

**Or**

```
cat /tmp/knp_snappy60f059079d55d8.51993277.html | wkhtmltopdf - test.pdf
```